# Are all legacy cameras exposed by camera2 (API level 21)?

Tags: android, camera, legacy

Are all API level 21 devices required to expose the camera2 package for all cameras(e.g. front,back) at least in the LEGACY support type?

In other words, is it possible(and does it happen) for a android 5 camera to be more functional under the deprecated android.hardware.Camera interface, than under the new android.hardware.camera2 interface, or even for the camera device to be impossible to find or use as a android.hardware.camera2 device?

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of the Android Compatibility Definition Document which does cover Camera API requirements: http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's mandatory that camera devices are exposed through android.hardware.camera2 (API2) as well as the deprecated android.hardware.Camera (API1).

However, at the LEGACY level, some features available in API1 may not be available in API2. Primarily, this affects the available recording resolutions, as LEGACY API2 is limited to the maximum preview size available in API1.

In addition, any OEM extensions to API1 won't be available through API2.